# How can i get the previous 6months in codeigniter(php)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making a billing page.

In here, i have to get the latest 6 year-month based on the current month.

For example,

if i use,

```
date('Ym')
```

i get 201308

and if i use,

```
date('Ym')-1
```

i get 201307

ok, fine! But the problem is,

what if the current month is 201301?

in this situation if i do

```
date('Ym')-1
```

I get 201300, but i need 201212.

Any good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `date()` for this. It wasn't made for it. Use [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) instead.

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->modify('-1 month');
echo $dt->format('Ym');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.org/QFOVVTAJ)

Or

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
echo $dt->format('Ym');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.org/4TbgWXv7)

Comment: Um... this is a little different question. But why do i have an error if i just put $dt = new DateTime(); If i don't put any params in here, isn't it default current time?